# WhatsApp Business api cloud: How do I register a Customer's phonenumber via api?

Tags: api, cloud, whatsapp

Currently, I am using WhatsApp Business api cloud on one of my web project, I would like to register a  customer's phone number but via api instead through meta, developer platform like following:

["Here is the image to register customer's number in the meta developer platform"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhdg8.png)

I want do this:
([managing the phone numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6KaX.png))

but via api, and later of that send the verification code via api as well.
If someone can help me , telling me if that is possible and sharing documentation or the endpoint I would appreciate it very much, I've been looking at the documentation and postman's examples for 2 days without any success.

I'm sorry I didn't share the pictures directly, it is my first question on Stackoverflow

Thanks in advance,
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using WhatsApp provided a test phone number in *From*, you need to read this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started#sent-test-message

> Enter the recipient phone number you would like to message in the To field. Ensure the number is correct, and **that you want to add it to your list of 5 possible message recipients** —as you add phone numbers, follow the prompts on the screen to verify you have access to them. **Once this number has been added, it cannot be removed from your list**.

> Note: This limitation is only for WhatsApp-provided test phone numbers. Real phone numbers that you register do not have a limit on the number of recipients.

You don't need to register receivers' phone numbers if you are using your own real business phone number in the sender's phone number.